# Ensure minimum number of observation per day for a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the data frame `newDat` below

```
Date1 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 02:00"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("2010-05-02 22:00"), by = 3600)
Dat <- data.frame(DateTime = Date1,
                   x1 = rnorm(length(Date1)))

Date2 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-03 02:00"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("2010-05-03 07:00"), by = 3600)
Dat2 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date2,
                  x1 = rnorm(length(Date2)))

newDat = rbind(Dat,Dat2)
```

I would like to generate a new data frame which only contains the days where there is more than 12 measurements recorded in a given day. In this particular example, the final day shown i.e. 2010-05-03 should be neglected seeing as only 6 measurements are recorded, all other days should remain. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` method:

```
library(data.table)
new.dt <- data.table(newDat)
subst <- new.dt[ , if (.N >= 12) x1, by=format(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Here is a method using `table` in base R:

```
newDat$date <- format(newDat$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d")
keep <- names(which(table(newDat$date) >= 12))
new.dt <- newDat[which(newDat$date %in% keep), ]
```